# Microsoft Flow and Outlook client

Tags: custom-list, flow

I have tried to create a workflow to copy entries from a personal Outlook calendar to a specific list in SharePoint. When I get to the source I can only add my calendar by adding the connection with my account. Is there a way for a global administrator to connect multiple people? The whole organization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow is not designed to do this, for security Flow can only connect to your calendar not other users.  Your best bet is to save the Flow as a template, then have the users that need the flow to run on their calendar use the template for their own Flow.